# IronPython ScriptRuntime equivalent to CPython PYTHONPATH

Tags: ironpython, c#-4.0

The following import works inside ipy.exe prompt but fails using IronPython ScriptRuntime inside a C# 4.0 program.

```
import ConfigParser
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

namespace CSharpDynamic
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            ScriptRuntime python = Python.CreateRuntime();
            dynamic dynamicIni =
python.UseFile(@"c:\test\WebCast\DynamicIni.py");

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

CPython uses PYTHONPATH environment variable. How do I configure this in IronPython when using ScriptRuntime?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to use GetSearchPaths and SetSearchPaths on your engine object.  You could parse the env variable of your choice and populate the search path when you initialize your engine.  For example:

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine(DefaultEngineOptions());
var paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
paths.Add("c:\\my_libs");
engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
```

Comment: The IronPython interpreter (ipe.exe) uses the IRONPYTHONPATH environment variable. It may be a good idea to read that into SetSearchPaths as well, depending on the application.