# Import embedded libs of IronPython

Tags: .net, ironpython

I've added IronPython Standart Library via NuGet into my c#.net4 project and later got some references(IronPython, IronPython.Modules, IronPython.SQLite, IronPython.Wpf, Microsoft.Dynamic, Microsoft.Scripting etc) and the 'Lib' folder contains python modules.
Now I'm trying to import the 'urllib' module in the my file.py but receiving the ImportException (No module named urllib).
How can I use urllib? Should I copy Lib folder to project output directory or do something else?

**UPD**: If I copy required modules to the project output directory then program works correctly without settings path.
May I use 'urllib' as embedded resource or import it in runtime?

Thanks!

Sources:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var url = new Uri("www.microsoft.com");
    var r = PythonHelper.Get(url);
}

public static class PythonHelper
{
    public static string Get(Uri url)
    {
        var programPath = @"PySources\GetPage.py";
        var py = new Py(programPath);
        py.Scope.SetVariable("url", url.ToString());
        py.Source.Execute();
        var result = py.Scope.GetVariable<string>("result");
        return result;
    }

    private class Py
    {
        public ScriptScope Scope { get; private set; }
        public ScriptSource Source { get; private set; }

        public Py(string pyPath)
        {
            var pyEngine = Python.CreateEngine();
            Scope = pyEngine.CreateScope();
            Source = pyEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(pyPath);
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            Source.Execute(Scope);
        }
    }
}

GetPage.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: windows-1251 -*-
#coding=windows-1251
#encoding=windows-1251

import clr
clr.AddReference("IronPython")
clr.AddReference('IronPython.Modules')

import urllib

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like     Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11"
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
result = urllib.urlopen(url, '' ,headers).read().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Your Libs folder has to be on the (python) path. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2224167/468244 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/1756818/468244 for related questions/answers. The section "How do I use CPython standard libraries?" on http://ironpython.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ also seems to hint in that direction.

Comment: Thank, Simon. I've read these articles, but I thought IronPython standard libraries can be used without installed Python.
My problem can be solved by copying Libs to application bin directory and I hope more eays way are exists.

Comment: some things like bzip2 or regex are implemented within IronPython.Modules.dll but that does not seem to be the case for urllib(2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can copy the Lib folder to your output directory. If you want it in a different directory you can use `ScriptEngine.SetSearchPaths()` to have complete control over the library path.

Another option is to put the standard library in a .zip file and add that using `ScriptEngine.SetSearchPaths()`, which at least reduces the number of files to send around.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff! Zip is optimal solution for me.