# Ironpython in C# Import Module Error import csv module

Tags: c#, python, csv, ironpython

I'm trying to execute a Python script from within a C# application but when it tries to launch the script, I receive the error `ImportException was unhandled` `No module name csv`.  I checked the Ironpython folder and there is a csv.py file...?

Code I'm using to call the script:

```
 IDictionary<string, object> options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
 options["Argument"] = new[] { filePath, profile };
 var pyEngine = Python.CreateEngine(options);
 var pyScope = pyEngine.CreateScope();
 string script = "xccdf-xml2tsv.py";
 pyScope.SetVariable(profile, options);

 pyEngine.ExecuteFile(script, pyScope);
```

python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

###
# (C) 2010 Adam Crosby
# Licensed under:
#  http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/
##
import csv
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xmlns = "http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.1"
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IronPython engine you created is unaware of the standard library implementation it should use. You can specify it by adding something like

```
var paths = pyEngine.GetSearchPaths();
paths.Add(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib");
pyEngine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
```

You could either point it to a locally installed iron python (as in my example) or use the [appropriate NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronPython.StdLib/) to directly add it to your project. You might also have to deploy it to your output folder/installer/...

Please also take note of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13883182/468244) as well as [this answer and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1756818/468244) as they might provide additional information.

Comment: Thanks, I had actually read both of those other posts already, just didn't realize the answer was right there. Does an app using IronPython require users to have it installed?

Comment: You can ship the required (subset of the) standard library with your application. So it depends on how you plan to roll out/deploy your application. You could for example have the core standard library as well as csv as a local copy within your project and ship that or bake it into your exe.

Comment: I installed the Nuget package but that did not solve the problem; I ended up with the code you have above. Seems like it will be a problem for users who don't have IronPython installed though...

Comment: You have to make sure the NuGet StdLib is copied with your app, and that the proper final location is added to the search path.