# Can I use IronPython to access regular Python Standard libraries?

Tags: ironpython

1.) I am using vb.net and c# and I just heard about IronPython. Can I use IronPython to access regular Python Standard libraries like nmap etc.?

2.) Can anyone give me an example of using nmap library in vb.net or c# by invoking nmap libray from IronPython?

Answer (score 0):

Look for other examples on how to instantiate the engine and run script.

But for accessing existing CPython packages you have installed you want to access the SearchPaths.

[IronPython ScriptRuntime equivalent to CPython PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755572/ironpython-scriptruntime-equivalent-to-cpython-pythonpath/1756818#1756818)