# IronPython, No module named in very simple case

Tags: python, ironpython

I Tried very simple dll importing, but no module named error appear.

My configuration are
 IronPython 2.7.5
 Install path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7"

1) my source foo.py:

```
class foo:
 def hello():
   print "hello"
```

2) Making dll module

```
ipy "Tools\Script\pyc.py" /main:foo.py / target:dll

--> Success, I got foo.dll
```

3) Check 1

```
ipy
>> import foo
>>

-->Importing Success
```

Check2

```
Delete source foo.py, leave only foo.dll
ipy
>> import clr
>> clr.AddReference("foo")
>> import foo

-> ImportError: No module named foo
```

I worked everything in "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7" directory.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do and why? Why are you compiling IronPython to a DLL to use it again from IronPython?

Comment: Thanks comment Simon.

In my plan,  some module are user customizable,  some module are fixed and secret for user. so I want release some module by dll only without source.

Comment: Just add the 'secret' modules to the search paths.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755572/ironpython-scriptruntime-equivalent-to-cpython-pythonpath/1756818#1756818  You gain nothing from compiling python to DLL.  IronPython is fast enough.